# ASP.NET Dynamic page generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, survey

I'm developing an online survey application for my University project.

I managed to save the newly created survey data into the database and now the problem is that i don't know **how to populate the saved questions** into a page (which sent to the customer to get responses) dynamically. And that response data should also be saved to the database.

Can anyone please help me  on this. I'm using ASP.NET for this.

Thanks

Comment: I can't exactly get what are you trying to do. Could you be more detailed?

Comment: agreed. no idea what you're trying to do, what do you mean by 'dynamic page generation', what is dynamic about what you're trying to do? Can you not just just have some simple CRUD operations? create/retrieve/update/delete questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need some database calls to get the questions.

- select (id, description) from questions

Then you need to populate this information into a Data Control.  I suggest a DataList or Repeater.

Assuming that the answers will be yes/no, you also need to add something like a RadioButtonList to collect the yes or no selection to the ItemTemplate.

You will need to submit the form, so a Button should be used.  In the click event, loop through each row of the DataList/Repeater and gather the answers.

Comment: Thanks Cen for yout early reply. This is very helpful and can I add the user responses like free text (not radio buttons) in the same way you suggest ?

Comment: You can add anything you want.  Add them like you normally would (id & runat tags required)

Comment: Hash did you find this helpful?  If so, do you mind marking the question as answered so others can see the answer too?  Thanks!